# Where can I find a sample print release form for business/commercial photographs?

Tags: legal, contracts

I photographed a business portrait session a month ago for the first time, and need a print release to go with it. The print release I have now is for personal portraits and states that the images cannot be used for commercial uses. The client needs them for use on websites and company profiles, etc. What kind of a print release form should I send to them? Does anybody know of a sample print release I can use? Thanks!

Comment: Which country should this conform to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The American Society of Media Photographers not only has a very useful tutorial on this subject, but they also have, as you requested, sample forms, [available here](http://asmp.org/tutorials/property-and-model-releases.html#.UKE9OuOe_v0) -- and unlike other pro orgs that lock their samples behind a login, these are freely available.

Answer (score 1):

[Easy Release](http://www.applicationgap.com/apps/easyrelease/), an iPhone/Android mobile application, generates release forms that are okay for photo agencies, so they should be fine for your client too.

Answer (score 0):

http://e-model.net/info/mr.html

This is a very good sample release.

Comment: That's a model release instead of a print release.